# In $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$: If $\langle u,v \rangle$ is a maximal ideal, then $\langle u-\lambda,v-\mu \rangle$ is a maximal ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $u=u(x,y), v=v(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, with $\deg(u) \geq 2$ and $\deg(v) \geq 2$.
Let $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$.

Assume that the ideal generated by $u$ and $v$, $\langle u,v \rangle$, is a *maximal* ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

> Is it true that $\langle u-\lambda, v-\mu \rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

My attempts to answer my question are:

**(1)** By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $\langle u,v \rangle= \langle x-a,y-b \rangle$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, so
$x-a=F_1u+G_1v$ and $y-b=F_2u+G_2v$, for some $F_1,G_1,F_2,G_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.
Then, $x=F_1u+G_1v+a$ and $y=F_2u+G_2v+b$.

**(2)** $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle u,v \rangle}$ is a field (since $\langle u,v \rangle$ is maximal); actually, $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle u,v \rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle u,v \rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle u-\lambda,v-\mu \rangle}$? In other words, is it true that $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle u-\lambda,v-\mu \rangle}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?
See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536060/show-that-quotient-ring-of-a-bbb-c-algebra-by-a-maximal-ideal-is-isomorphic-t?rq=1) question.

**(3)** If $\langle u-\lambda,v-\mu \rangle$ is not maximal, then it is contained in some maximal ideal: $\langle u-\lambda,v-\mu \rangle \subsetneq \langle x-c,y-d \rangle$, $c,d \in \mathbb{C}$.
It is not difficult to see that $(u-\lambda)(c,d)=0$ and $(v-\mu)(c,d)=0$,
so $u(c,d)-\lambda=0$ and $v(c,d)-\mu=0$, namely,
$u(c,d)=\lambda$ and $v(c,d)=\mu$.

**Remark:** Is it possible that $\langle u-\lambda,v-\mu \rangle = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. If so, then there exist $F,G \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that
$F(u-\lambda)+G(v-\mu)=1$. Then at $(a,b)$ we get:
$F(a,b)(-\lambda)+G(a,b)(-\mu)=1$ (since, by **(1)**, $u(a,b)=0$ and $v(a,b)=0$).

Thank you very much!

Now also at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366015/in-mathbbcx-y-if-langle-u-v-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-then-langle).

Comment: The isomorphism desired in (2) does not hold in general. consider, e.g. $u \equiv v \equiv 1$ and $\lambda = \mu = 1$.

Comment: Thank you. It was assumed that $\deg(u) \geq 2$ and $\deg(v) \geq 2$; perhaps the desired isomorphism in (2) may not hold also in higher degrees?

Comment: Standard algebraic geometry tells us that maximal ideals containing $(f,g)$ correspond to common zeroes of $f$ and $g$. With this in mind, $(f,g)$ is maximal if and only if $f$ and $g$ have exactly one common zero and they're not tangent when they intersect. E.g. $y = x^2$ and $y = -x^2$ only have $(0,0)$ as a common zero but it has multiplicity two and we have $(y - x^2, y + x^2) = (y,x^2)$.

Comment: One thing that gets in the way of constructing examples where $(f,g)$ is maximal is [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem) which says there will always be $\deg f \cdot \deg g$ common zeroes with multiplicity in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. Somehow we want to have all but one of these zeroes to be "at infinity." The only example I've come up with so far is something like $(y - x^2, y - (x + 1)^2) = (2x + 1, 4y - 1)$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn, thank you for your interesting comments (unfortunately, I am not sure if I fully understand them). Could you please elaborate your example?

Comment: @user237522 The main goal is to show that $u, v$ have only one common zero (with multiplicity). I started with degree 2 to reduce the possible number of common zeroes. Then I took a simple quadratic, namely the parabola $y = x^2$ and just shifted it over by $1$ so it only intersects in 1 real point (and it turns out, only in 1 complex point).

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I wrote a comment on the re-post this question on MathOverflow and then deleted it because I had misread the question. The automorphism I mentioned there looks irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: (My comment here should go on MathOverflow, but you've deleted the question there and so comments are disabled.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thank you. Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't true. The requirement that $\deg u$, $\deg v \geq 2$ is annoying, so I'll first solve the problem without this and then tweak my example to add this condition. As already explained in other answers, saying that $\langle u,v \rangle$ is maximal means that the curves $\{ u = 0 \}$ and $\{ v=0 \}$ intersect at a unique point, and cross transversely there. We want to find polynomials such that this is true for $u$ and $v$, but not for $u-\lambda$ and $v-\lambda$.

An example is to take $u = xy^2 + y + x$ and $v=x$. Then $u-(y^2+1) v = y$, so it is easy to see that $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$. But $u=0$, $v=2/5$ has two roots, at $x=2/5$, $y \in \{ 2, 1/2 \}$.  (Almost any value of $v$ would have worked; I chose one that made the $y$-coordinates rational.) Here is a plot of the curve $u=0$ together with $v=0$ and $v=2/5$:

[image]

Now we have to tweak this to make $\deg v$ be $\geq 2$ rather than $1$. Take $u=xy^2+y+x$ and $v_2 = xy^2 + y$, so $v_2 = u-v$. Then $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle u,v_2 \rangle$ and $\langle u,v-2/5 \rangle = \langle u, v_2+2/5 \rangle$ so $\langle u,v \rangle$ is a maximal ideal and $\langle u, v_2+2/5 \rangle$ is not.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Update 19/07/2020** This approach does not work and the statement is in fact, not true. See David Speyer's answer instead.

The issue is that $\overline{u - \lambda}(x,y,0) = \bar{u}(x,y,0)$ and $\overline{v - \mu}(x,y,0) = \bar{v}(x,y,0)$ only implies that $\{u = 0\} \cap \{v = 0\}$ and $\{u = \lambda \} \cap \{v = \mu\}$ have the same set of zeroes at infinity, *not that the multiplicities are equal.*

For example $u(x,y) = x$ and $v(x,y) = xy - 1$ versus $u'(x,y) = x - 1$. These have $[0:1:0]$ as a common zero at infinity but to get the multiplicity we need to look at $\overline{u'}(x,1,z) = x - z$ and $\overline{v}(x,1,z) = x - z^2$ rather than just setting $z = 0$.

---

By the Nullstellensatz $(u, v)$ is maximal if and only if $V(u,v)$ is a single (closed) point.

> Why is this? First suppose $(u,v)$ is maximal. Then you're comfortable with saying that $(u,v) = (x - a, y - b)$ by the (weak) Nullstellensatz. Thus $$V(u,v) = V(x - a, y - b) = \{(a,b)\}$$
> is a single point.

> Conversely, if $V(u,v) = \{(a,b)\}$ is a single point, then the (strong) Nullstellensatz tells us that $$\operatorname{rad}(u,v) = I(V(u,v)) = I(\{(a,b)\}) = (x - a, y - b).$$
> The condition that $(u,v) = \operatorname{rad}(u,v)$ is the same as saying $(a,b)$ doesn't have extra multiplicity as a common zero.

Let $\bar{u}(x,y,z)$ and $\bar{v}(x,y,z)$ be the homogenizations of $u, v$. By [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), $V(\bar{u},\bar{v}) \subseteq \mathbb{CP}^2$ consists of $\deg(\bar{u})\deg(\bar{v}) = \deg(u)\deg(v)$ points counted with multiplicity.

By the first observation, $V(u,v)$ consists of $1$ point, meaning the other $\deg(u)\deg(v) - 1$ points occur at infinity. I.e. they are the common zeroes of $\bar{u}(x,y,0)$ and $\bar{v}(x,y,0)$

If we modify $u, v$ by adding $\lambda, \mu$ then the new homogenizations are

$$ \overline{u - \lambda} = \bar{u} + \lambda z^{\deg u}, \quad \overline{v - \mu} = \bar{u} + \mu z^{\deg u} $$

Since $\overline{u - \lambda}(x,y,0) = \bar{u}(x,y,0)$ and $\overline{v - \mu}(x,y,0) = \bar{v}(x,y,0)$ it is also true that $\overline{u - \lambda}$ and $\overline{v - \mu}$ have $\deg(u)\deg(v) - 1$ common zeroes at infinity.

Thus $u - \lambda, v - \mu$ have exactly one common zero not at infinity, so by the Nullstellensatz, $(u - \lambda, v - \mu)$ is maximal.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I am still not familiar with algebraic geometry (I had a feeling that algebraic geometry may help. Several pure algebraic questions I have asked in the past got excellent answers relying on algebraic geometry). I hope that your answer is correct.

Comment: @user237522 I've added some explanation of why we are looking at common zeroes with multiplicity 1. Unfortunately, it's hard to give a good explaination of the multiplicity 1 condition without more algebraic geometry but I hope that modulo that, you are able to follow my reasoning.

Comment: Thank you very much again! I have some gaps in understanding your answer, but hopefully it is correct. (I have upvoted it, since it 'seems' correct).

Comment: There is a paper I wish to write, in which your answer will be helpful. Please, could you email me user237522mse@gmail.com I will give you more details about the paper, and you will let me know if you want to be a co-author or just being quoted+acknowledged. (I will probably email you back tomorrow, since now it is very late at night here).

Comment: This doesn't work, see my answer.

Comment: The problem is that, while it is true that replacing $(u,v)$ with $(u+\lambda, v+\mu)$ doesn't change the zeroes at infinity as a set, it can change the multiplicity of those zeroes.

Comment: Thank you @David, I understand what my mistake was now. I'm going to leave the answer up with an explanation of the error in case people can learn from my mistake.

Comment: @user237522 You should probably un-accept this answer and (if you think it answers your question) accept David Speyer's instead.

Comment: Think of $\{=0 \} \cap \{=1 \}$ (no common zeroes in $\mathbb{A}^2$, zero at vertical infinity has multiplicity 2) versus $\{=1 \} \cap \{ =1\}$ (zero at (1,1), zero at vertical infinity has multiplicity 1.)

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed a typo in one of my comments above, so I deleted it and replaced it with the example in the comment above this one.