# A characterization of a maximal ideal in a polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $I$ be a proper ideal in $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, generated by two elements
$f_1,f_2$, $I=\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle$.

I wonder if the following claim is true or false:

> **Claim:** If for every $c_1,c_2,d,e \in \mathbb{C}$, each of the ideals
> $\langle f_1-c_1,f_2-c_2,x-d \rangle$ and $\langle f_1-c_1,f_2-c_2,y-e \rangle$
> is either maximal or $R$,
> then there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $I_{a,b}=\langle f_1-a,f_2-b \rangle$
> is a maximal ideal of $R$.

**Examples:**
**(1)** $f_1=x(x+1), f_2=y$, so $I_{a,b}=\langle x(x+1)-a,y-b \rangle$ is not maximal,
for every $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

In this case, take $c_1=c_2=e=0$ and get that
$\langle x(x+1)-0, y-0, y-0 \rangle=\langle x(x+1), y \rangle$ is not maximal and not equals $R$.

**(2)** $f_1=x+y, f_2=y^2+y$, so $I=\langle x+y,y^2+y \rangle$ is not maximal,
it has two common zeros: $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$.
It is clear that all $\langle x+y-c_1,y^2+y-c_2,x-d \rangle$ and
$\langle x+y-c_1,y^2+y-c_2,y-e \rangle$ are maximal or $R$.
Here, taking $a=0,b=-\frac{1}{4}$ seems to make $I$ maximal:
$I_{0,-\frac{1}{4}}=\langle x+y,y^2+y+\frac{1}{4}\rangle=\langle x+y,(y+\frac{1}{2})^2 \rangle$; if I am not wrong it is maximal, having one common zero $(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$.

**Remarks:**
**(1)** The one-dimensional case says: If for every $c \in \mathbb{C}$,
$I=\langle f-c \rangle$ (adding no generator) is either maximal or $\mathbb{C}[x]$,
then there exists $a \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $I=\langle f-a \rangle$ is maximal;
here it follows that $f$ is linear (and we can take any $a \in \mathbb{C}$), since if $f=\tilde{c} \in \mathbb{C}$,
then taking the scalar $\tilde{c}$ would yield the zero ideal $\langle \tilde{c}-\tilde{c} \rangle=\langle 0 \rangle$ which is not maximal and not $\mathbb{C}[x]$.

**(2)** I wonder if there exists a known algebraic geometry result which would solve my question.

**(3)** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042104/in-mathbbcx-y-if-langle-u-v-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-then-langle?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a relevant question.

Any comments are welcome; thank you!

**EDIT:** In view of the nice comment, I would like to add one of the following conditions:

*Condition 1:* For every $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$, $I_{\alpha,\beta}=\langle f_1-\alpha,f_2-\beta \rangle$ is a prime ideal.

*Condition 2:* For every $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$, $I_{\alpha,\beta}=\langle f_1-\alpha,f_2-\beta \rangle$ is a radical ideal.

Comment: For example, take $f_1=x-y, f_2=(x+y)^2$. Then all ideals with fixed $x$ or $y$ are maximal or equal to $R$, but all ideals $I_{a, b}$ are not maximal.

Comment: @danneks, oh, you are right; thank you very much! Please, do you think it is possible to obtain a similar (valid) condition on an ideal to imply it is maximal?

Comment: Could one find a counterexample where $I_{s,t}=\langle f_1-s,f_2-t\rangle$ is a radical ideal, for all $s,t \in \mathbb{C}$? In the above counterexample, $I_{s,0}$ is non-radical, for all $s \in \mathbb{C}$. $f_1=x-y,f_2=xy$ does not help, since it is not a radical ideal, if I am not wrong, since $x^2 \in \langle x-y,xy \rangle$, but $x \notin \langle x-y,xy \rangle$.